# Select dummy values if where clause returns zero rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2016. I have a SQL and it has where clause which returns zero or non-zero rows depending on data present in the table at a specific time. For example the SQL is:

```
select step_id,
       step_name
  from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
 where step_id = 9999
```

What I want is when the SQL returns zero rows, then it should return one row with dummy values that I can specify.

**What I tried:** I can do this by using this SQL:

```
DECLARE @Condition int 
SET @Condition = 0;
IF (
    SELECT count(*) FROM
    (
     select step_id,
            step_name
       from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
       where step_id = 9999
    ) t1
   ) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @Condition = 1;
END;

IF @Condition = 1
BEGIN
select step_id,
       step_name
  from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
 where step_id = 9999
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 123456 AS [step_id], 'There are no step_id matching the WHERE clause' AS [step_name]
END
```

**Question:** But here I am running the same SQL twice. I want to know if there is any better way to do this.

Comment: Really depends on what you're going to do: One idea would be like IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 return Dummyrow

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Exteban. I want just one result set with resulting row (if where clause returns some row/s) or with dummy values (if where clause returns zero rows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that if the WHERE clause eliminates all rows, you end up with an empty set.

One way around it, is to use an aggregate function to force one row in the result.

Then, with COALESCE (or ISNULL), you can assign your default values.

This solution is only feasible if:

- your basic query always returns exactly 0 or 1 row
- your columns do not contain NULL
- the selected columns can be aggregated (e.g. it will not work for text columns)
- your default values have the same data type as the columns

For example:

```
select COALESCE(MAX(step_id),123456) AS step_id,
       COALESCE(MAX(step_name),'There are no step_id matching the WHERE clause') AS step_name
  from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
 where step_id = 9999
```

Comment: Worked like magic. I'll study it to understand better. First two & fourth conditions were true. The second column in the basic SQL is nvarchar/text but it still worked. Thank you for your valuable response.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler way to accomplish the same thing. No need for variables and such.

```
select step_id,
    step_name
from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
where step_id = 9999

if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    SELECT 123456 AS [step_id], 'There are no step_id matching the WHERE clause' AS [step_name]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Sean. This works the way I want but it pull two result sets. First with zero rows and second with dummy values. Is there a way to get single result set with dummy rows when the SQL returns zero rows?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option, just for comparison (it returns your dummy row in the same  table as your main results, if you don't have main results).

```
DECLARE @search_ID INT = 999;

WITH data
AS (SELECT step_id, step_name
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 12345, 'dummy') --Insert your dummy data here

SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE step_id = @search_ID
      OR
      (   step_id = 12345
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM data WHERE step_id = @search_ID)
      );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response APH but I am getting syntax error near `WITH step_id,` for `,`.  Error is: `Incorrect syntax near ','. Expecting '(', or AS.`

Comment: @300 sorry about that, I was copy-pasting to make my example work with your field names, and pasted the wrong thing.  Try it now :)